# React component not rerendering when props from redux store update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have a Navigation component that renders a List, the navigation tree is fetched from the server through useEffect and the props are updated.
In my redux-store I see the correct values, and even when I do a console.log of the navTree prop, I first get undefined and then the object that's expected, however my component isn't rerendering.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing.

```
const Navigation = ({navTree, initializeNavigation}) => {

    const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!initialized) {
            initializeNavigation();
            setInitialized(true);
        }
    }, [initialized, initializeNavigation]);

    console.log(navTree);

    if (navTree) {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {Object.keys(navTree).map(
                    key => {
                        console.log(key);
                        console.log(navTree);
                        if (navTree) console.log(navTree[key]);
                        return (
                            <List key={key}>
                                <ListItem>
                                    {key.toUpperCase()}
                                </ListItem>
                                <Divider/>
                                {navTree && navTree[key] && Object.keys(navTree[key]).map((entity) => (
                                    <ListItem button key={entity}>
                                        <ListItemText primary={entity.toUpperCase()}/>
                                    </ListItem>
                                ))}
                            </List>)
                    }
                )}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
    return null;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    navTree: selectors.getNavTree(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    initializeNavigation: () => dispatch(actions.buildNavigationTree())
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Navigation);
```

Comment: can you share the JSON of navTree object?

Comment: when I log the object I get a json looking like this {system: {currency: "/currency"}} but when I do a JSON.stringify it returns following string "‘{}"

Comment: this is the json how it's in my redux-store {
  "systeem": {
    "currency": "/currency"
  }
}

Comment: @J.Pip is `console.log` in render function called when you changed your store? If not, could you show code or your reducer and `selector.getNavTree`?

Comment: can you log us the navTree object please?

Comment: can you log us the navTree object please?